# continue work and commits on same branch after having reverted/ reset

Tags: git, git-commit, git-checkout, git-revert

Man, this git thing surely is a hard nut to crack!

So I have this branch:

a--b--c--d - mybranch

What I would do here is go back to commit 'b' and continue working and committing. but I would want to neither branch anew nor loose 'c' and 'd' commits. 
I have been reading about this git revert thing but can't wrap my head around it for all that is worth.

Help!

Comment: If you want to create new commits starting from `b` **and** keep `c` and `d`, you must create a branch.

Answer (score 1):

As stated before, there is no way to do this without creating a new branch (unless you want to get into some risky business with the 'ref' history and commits that haven't been garbage collected, which isn't worth it in this scenario when a simple solution exists).

Create a new branch to store the commits you want to save, but don't want in your `mybranch`.

`git checkout -b newBranch`

Go back to `mybranch` in order to remove commits 'c' and 'd'.

`git checkout mybranch`

`git reset --hard b`

Now you can continue your work in `mybranch` from commit 'b'. Later, if you want to bring commits 'c' and 'd' back into `mybranch`, you can just do a `git merge newBranch` from `mybranch`.